# What is the right way of getting the current Firebase user in every screen?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I successfully setup an app with Flutter with both registration and login with Firebase Authentication.

After the sign-in I come back to the home-screen, where I get the user with:

```dart
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseUser user;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initUser();
  }

  initUser() async {
    user = await _auth.currentUser();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        //appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Run to Feel Better")),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              if (user == null)
                RoundedButton(
                  buttonTitle: 'Crea un account',
                  color: kRTFBBlue,
                  onPressedFunction: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/account');
                  },
                )
              else
                Text("${user?.email}"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: bottomBar(context, 0),
      ), // /widgets/home_scaffold.dart
    );
  }
}
```

So, everything works fine, but my question is: what is the right way to get the current user in other pages? Have I to recheck in every screen with FirebaseAuth.instance, or can I save it and share between pages (maybe with Provider package)?

Thank-you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can do both, i.e. you can store your `FirebaseAuth` instance somewhere using [state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options), however, you can also just call `FirebaseAuth.instance` all the time.

The only valuable insight I could think of is that calling `FirebaseAuth.instance` is totally fine (not particularly expensive) - everything else is probably just entirely opinion based.